# What happens when I hover over a link in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, crash

When this link (`http://a//%%30%30`) is clicked in Google Chrome, Chrome breaks and closes all tabs and instances.

But, in some cases I only need to hover over the link, and the tab crashes.

What happens when I hover over this link? I mean, what does Chrome do when a link is hovered over?

Comment: Here's a great Tom Scott video that talks about what he thinks is happening in chrome https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fw5Cyh21TE

Comment: This bug was fixed in [Chrome 45.0.2454.101](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/2015/09/stable-channel-update_24.html).  It was still present in [Chrome 45.0.2454.99](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/2015/09/stable-channel-refresh.html).

Comment: The bug is _not_ fixed in Chrome 45.0.2454.101 (at least on Mac OS 10.10.5 Chrome is still crashing).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The crash is due to a recently discovered bug in **Chrome** - and other [WebKit browsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers)(!)* - specifically related to either `%%30%30`, `%0%30` or `%%300` as part of the URL, which internally all end up representing the same symbol: **null**. You can read more about the bug [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=533361#c36).

It's not a bug that affect most links, so you don't generally have to worry about hovering over links.

**Notes:**
* Other [WebKit browsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers) include Safari, Opera, Steam Browser, Midori, S60 (Symbian), Blackberry Browser and Playstation 3's browser - **but not** Firefox, Internet Explorer or Edge.

Edit:
This bug has now been fixed in [Chrome 45.0.2454.101](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/2015/09/stable-channel-update_24.html) as [Deltik](https://superuser.com/users/83694/deltik) points out.

### More about what happens

The problem is related to the **URL canonicalizer**, which runs as soon as you hover over a link - possibly for displaying the link in the status bar of the browser, and for [prefetching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_prefetching) the webpage so it loads faster once clicked.

As for the role of the URL canonicalizer:
When a URL is written in `HTML`, it may be written in a form such as `/home` or `../../home`, but browsers need to translate this URL to something with a protocol and a domain too, like `http://superuser.com/home`. Furthermore the URL may contain [URL Escapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url_escape) that need to be *translated*, and these *escapes* are *percent encoded*, like `%%30%30`. (A more exhaustive list of URL escapes [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)).
The functionality handling this *URL translation*  is what's ending up crashing, because it receives input the developers did not expect/handle.

[Here's](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/8a20d0a7ce44afada2014ddcbc0b1909cf9c76b6) a summary of the code change that fixed the problem:

> Correctly handle problematic nested escapes in URL paths.
>
> Specifically, if unescaping in the input leads to the output URL
>   containing a new escaped sequence, e.g. converting the input "%%30%30"
>   to "%00", escape the leading '%' as "%25" to ensure the output
>   sequence is not treated as a new valid escape sequence.
>
> This ensures that canonicalizing the same URL a second time won't make
>   changes to it, which is important for avoiding crashes and other bugs
>   in a variety of places in both debug and release builds.

Comment: For clarity, no issue with FireFox or IE 11

Comment: Considering Opera is based on the Chrome engine that is not shocking that it also crashes.  Which is the reason having multiple rendering engines is a good thing.

Comment: But why it happens **on hover**? I mean, when I hover a link, there's no search, so why it crashes?

Comment: It's not yet clear what's causing the bug, but some think it's related to the `URL canonicalizer`, which apparently starts running as soon as you hover over a link, maybe for displaying the link in the status bar of the browser? I can't give you a certain answer, however when a URL is written in HTML, it may be written in a form such as `/home` or `../../home` , but browsers need to translate this URL to something with a protocol and a domain too, like `http://superuser.com/home`, so maybe the functionality handling that is what's ending up crashing, because it receives unexpected input?

Comment: Some browsers start downloading a page if they think you will want to load it, even if you didn't click any link yet.

Comment: By the way, it also crashes Steam's internal browser.

Comment: @JéfersonBueno When you hover over a link, Chrome displays it in the lower left corner. This requires some processing, including the "translation" of specially encoded characters. This processing is buggy, and causes the entire program to crash.

Comment: For clarity, only Opera 15+ crashes, since 12.17 and older have the awesome Presto engine, while the new "browser" versions use Blink.

Answer (score 11):

As Fabio Turati says,

> When you hover over a link, Chrome displays it in the lower left corner. This requires some processing, including the "translation" of specially encoded characters.

However, from your post and comment I think you are more concerned about whether Chrome connects to the link in the background. [It does](https://www.igvita.com/2012/06/04/chrome-networking-dns-prefetch-and-tcp-preconnect/), so do other modern browsers([Firefox](http://www.ghacks.net/2013/04/27/firefox-prefetching-what-you-need-to-know/), [Opera](http://browserfame.com/922/dns-prefetch-opera)). You may want to disable prefetching in Chrome's preferences, or install [uBlock Origin](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock) to get more privacy settings.

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to give some further clarification on what exactly happens here.

Basically, %30 is an URL-encoded 0, and %00 is a URL-encoded NULL (which is displayed in binary as 0000 0000). So if you have a URL that has a nested encoded character that will decode to NULL, the bug occurs.

Chrome does the following when canonicalizing a URL (source:https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=533361#c13) :

> - An input string "http: //a.com/%%30%30" is unescaped to "http://a.com/%00" and considered a valid GURL.
> - This GURL is eventually sent to GURLToDatabaseURL(), which calls ReplaceComponents() on it to strip the username and password.
> - ReplaceComponents() re-canonicalizes the URL.
> - Canonicalization of the path hits the "%00" sequence, unescapes, sees this is a 0 char which is invalid in URLs, leaves it escaped, but
>     marks the resulting URL as invalid.
> - Once we return back to GURLToDatabaseURL(), it calls .spec() on the new URL, expecting it to be valid, since the input URL was guaranteed
>     to be valid and we merely removed the username and password.  This
>     DCHECKs.

So the URL is first considered valid, but after removing certain private data, it's invalidated. However, after that data is removed, the function that called that particular code expects a valid URL.

Part of the reason why this URL is considered invalid is because NULL is used in a number of older software and languages to indicate the end of a string (because it's basically 8 zeroes in a line, which is easy to detect for a computer).